# How can I disable the certificate check in Anaconda virtual environment with geopy

Tags: python, ssl, anaconda, conda, geopy

When running the code below in Python 2.7.10 under Anaconda with no Conda virtual environment, it works fine. That's one year ago.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()
location = geolocator.reverse("16.890568, 42.543554", language="en")
```

Got this error if running the same code now in Anaconda Conda virtual environment in which the root is Python 3.6 and the used virtual environment is Python 2.7.

```
GeocoderServiceError: 
  <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)>
```

Tried to search SO, Google and check [geopy](http://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), still found no answer. During the search, it seems that to disable ssl certificate check might be a viable solution but don't know how. Welcome for any advice.

Comment: It's not recommend to disable, try [python-certifi](https://github.com/certifi/python-certifi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Come across this [site](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/python-27-how-disable-ssl-certificate-verification-yakov-falevich) and got the workaround to make it works again. Just insert the try-except-else code before assigning the `geolocator`.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

# Disable SSL certificate verification 
try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    # Legacy Python that doesn't verify HTTPS certificates by default
    pass
else:
    # Handle target environment that doesn't support HTTPS verification
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context

location = geolocator.reverse("16.890568, 42.543554", language="en")
```